# Performance of Pure TCL vs TCL C API's for populating a TCL array

Tags: tcl

Will reading a file using TCL C API's and populating a TCL array be much faster compared 
to doing the same with standard TCL. I have a large file about 100+MB which I need to read and set some hash entries. Using TCL C API's doesn't seems to provide atmost 2 to 4 times speed advantage. Is this usual or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You're unlikely to get much of a performance gain in this case, as when you're setting array entries from the C API, you're bearing much of the cost that you'd experience if you just wrote the code as Tcl *inside a procedure*. In particular, you could very easily get *worse* performance through using an inefficient sub-API; some of Tcl's API functions are not very fast (e.g., `Tcl_SetVar`) but they're kept because of the large amount of existing code that uses them (and the fact that the faster functions require more C code to use). Bear in mind that setting an array element requires a *mandatory* hash table lookup, and those have a real cost (despite the fact that Tcl uses a very fast — if rather stupid — hash).

What's more, you can get better performance by using a Tcl list or dictionary (depending on what exactly you want to store) and the C API to those is quite quick (especially for lists, which are really C arrays of `Tcl_Obj` references). What I don't know is whether doing that would be a suitable substitute for your purposes.

Comment: Tcl's hash function is really bone-headed, and I've looked rather hard at whether it can be improved, but it's **really hard** to actually make it better. Anything done to distribute the keys better makes the function quite a bit slower (yes, I tried with a whole bunch of functions) in the cases that come up most commonly in Tcl scripts. I thought it was a rather disappointing result. (It did shake a number of evil finalization bugs out of the woodwork though.)

Comment: Thanks Donal. I will try to see if we can improve the original TCL code using lists instead of using an array.

Answer (score 2):

The C API is there primarily to allow you to write Tcl extensions and just exposes the routines that 'pure Tcl' itself is written in. In a case like you describe I wouldn't expect to see much performance difference and remember:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
> it) in programming.
>
> Computer Programming as an Art (1974) by Donald Knuth

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to load lots of data, maybe some extension like NAP (http://wiki.tcl.tk/4015) or similar would be appropriate?

Comment: schlenk, I am using flex and bison to process a input file which is then translated to an array. Not sure if NAP will help in my case.